# Как изменить цвет выделения текста в Pycharm?

Tags: color, text, pycharm

Например, когда установлена тема Monokai, то очень плохо видно выделенный текст мышкой.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно настроить свойство `Selection background` в настройках:

1. Откройте окно настроек (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> или *File → Settings* или <kbd>Double Shift</kbd>)
2. Зайдите в пункт меню *Editor → Colors & Fonts → General* и найдите пункт списка `Selection background` или воспользуйтесь строкой поиска:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Answer (score 0):

В Settings выбираем из дерева Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General. Меняем цвета того, что нужно